# javascript more functions in one time

Tags: javascript, function, time, counter

for a school project i need to make a second screen for several devices. I will fake the screen changes by time. So lets say on 10 minutes it has to show this div id=one and on 20 minutes it has to show div id=two. unfortunately my code is not working and i cant find the problem. Maybe the way i think is also not correct.

Your feedback is welcome and many thanks in advance

```
  var counter = 0;
   var i = setInterval(function(){
    // do your thing

    counter++;
    if(counter === 1000) {
        document.getElementById("DoeDitVooralWelThuis").style.display ="block";
      document.getElementById("remaintime").style.display ="none";
    }
    counter++;
    if(counter === 2000) {
        document.getElementById("ExperimentArea").style.display ="block";
      document.getElementById("DoeDitVooralWelThuis").style.display ="none";
    }
 `enter code here`};
```

Comment: What is actually happening when you run it at the moment? For a start, you've set it to run on 1 second and 2 seconds.

Comment: You either didn't provided complete code or it is ill-formatted javascript. Argument list for `setInterval` is not closed and there is no delay value.  Also, `setTimeout` is much more appropiate for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set timer using `setTimeout()`.

```
function showFirst() {
    document.getElementById("DoeDitVooralWelThuis").style.display ="block";
    document.getElementById("remaintime").style.display ="none";
}
setTimeout(showFirst, 600000);//after 10 minutes

function showSecond() {
    document.getElementById("ExperimentArea").style.display ="block";
    document.getElementById("DoeDitVooralWelThuis").style.display ="none";
}
setTimeout(showSecond, 1200000);//after 20 minutes
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The second `counter++` is not needed. 
There are also syntax errors in your code such as unclosed brackets.

To make the screens change on 10 minutes and 20 minutes, you need to use 
`if(counter === (1000 * 60) * 10) {` 

`1000`  equals 1000 milliseconds, which is one second. So you have to multiply that by sixty to get One minute, and then by ten to get ten minutes. Same with twenty.

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var counter = 0;
    var i = setInterval(function(){

    counter++;
    if(counter === (1000 * 60) * 10) {
        document.getElementById("secondScreenElement").style.display ="block";
        document.getElementById("firstScreenElement").style.display ="none";
    }

    if(counter === (2000 * 60) * 10) {
        document.getElementById("secondScreenElement").style.display ="none";
        document.getElementById("thirdScreenElement").style.display ="block";
        clearInterval(i);
    }
 });
};
```

If you want to stop changing between screens after the last screen has been displayed, you can use `clearInterval` and pass it the value of your `setInterval`. ie - `clearInterval(i);`
Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/njkyk2ff/3/) here. I have used 1 and two seconds in this fiddle.

Comment: No problem :) gotta love those school projects.